# xUnit - test that one of two distinct exceptions is thrown

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
Type exceptionDuplicate = UseInMemoryDb ? typeof(ArgumentException) : typeof(DbUpdateException);
Assert.Throws<exceptionDuplicate> (() => context.SaveChanges());
```

This does not work as Assert.Throws wants a type, not a variable inside the <>. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What about having two different tests, one for each value of that setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Assert` class has an overload that takes a `Type`  as first argument see [GitHub](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/ExceptionAsserts.cs#L162).

```
public static Exception Throws(Type exceptionType, Func<object> testCode)
```

Your code then looks like below.

```
Type exceptionDuplicate = UseInMemoryDb ? typeof(ArgumentException) : typeof(DbUpdateException);
Assert.Throws(exceptionDuplicate, () => context.SaveChanges());
```

Comment: First off - that works. Thank you. Second, why did the <exceptionDuplicate> not work? Does that require an explicit type as opposed to a variable of type Type?

Comment: That `Assert.Throws<>(...)` overload expects a [generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) which cannot be constructed from a `typeof` call.